# echo out a php variable inside a class

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to echo out a php variable inside a div like that `<div class="kor $value">`

```
 $value = get_theme_mod( 'ani', 'fadeIn' );
$output .= apply_filters( 'wal') ? '<div class="kor' <?php echo $value' ">':'');
```

Comment: You should read the documentation about strings. It explains the basic syntax, which you're failing to get right.

Comment: in php variables aren't parsed inside single quotes. use double quotes or break out of the single quotes

Comment: syntax issues php inside php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be declaring another php block inside an existing one, and also not using the . to join strings together. And there's a bracket problem too.

Here's a fixed version:

```
$output .= (apply_filters('wal') ? '<div class="kor'.$value.' ">' : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have alreay defined  $output   you should use  concat string

```
   $output .= apply_filters( 'wal') ?  '<div class="kor' .  $value . ' ">':'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `echo`. You just have to concatenate the value. besides the `)` at the end of second line will throw an error. Try this:

```
$output .= apply_filters( 'wal') ? '<div class="kor'.$value.'">':'';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP separates strings with dot. So put your var between dots. Like this:

```
 $output .= apply_filters( 'wal') ? '<div class="kor'.$value.'">':'');
```